# Using the Full Screen

Tags: c#, vector, fullscreen, monogame

I am using MonoGame in full screen.  The following code only puts my X and Y about 2/3 of the way over.  How can I make it go all the way to the bottom right of the full screen?

```
position.X = (float) this.Window.ClientBounds.Width;
position.Y = (float) this.Window.ClientBounds.Height;
```

When Full Screen is not enabled, then the X and Y are out of the Window and not visible.

This is driving me nuts!  I have tried every option I have seen in Visual Studio, but still cannot figure it out!

The person is supposed to be at the bottom right of the screen:

[image]

Update:

I can statically change it with

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = someNumber;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = someOtherNumber;
```

But I would like to be able to have it work dynamically for all screen resolutions instead of just mine.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a combination of XNA and MonoTouch, so this may be an XNA related fix, but have you tried using the Window object? Ex:

```
position.X = this.Window.ClientBounds.Left;
position.Y = this.Window.ClientBounds.Bottom;
```

This should grab the current window position....

E: If the client bounds aren't the correct dimensions, maybe the DisplayWindow will do it?

```
position.X = this.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width;
position.Y = this.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height;
```

Comment: Is it starting in the same place? Are you changing the screen resolution after you do this or the one you posted? Where is it putting the character now?

Comment: same thing. no changes

Comment: hmmm... ok. As I asked before, do you change the screen resolution after you set the postition.X and Y? What Are the client bounds currently? I think I may have found a solution, check my edit